# What questions about Stack Overflow for Teams should be asked here?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

On Meta Stack Exchange, the description for its [*stack-overflow-for-teams*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams) says:

> Most questions about Stack Overflow for Teams (a private Stack Overflow environment for a group of developers) should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

Is that tag description correct? If it is, what questions about *Stack Overflow for Teams* should be asked on Meta Stack Exchange, and not here?